# Do the parentheses like "()" in the following code have some meaning?

Tags: python, tensorflow

The python code is:

```
 #========= RPN ============
 (self.feed('conv5_3').conv(3,3,512,1,1,name='rpn_conv/3x3'))
 (self.feed('rpn_conv/3x3').lstm(512,128,name='lstm_o'))
 (self.feed('lstm_o').lstm_bbox(128,len(anchor_scales) * 10 * 4, name='rpn_bbox_pred'))
 (self.feed('lstm_o').lstm_bbox(128,len(anchor_scales) * 10 * 2,name='rpn_cls_score'))
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

No, all of the **outer** parentheses are redundant.

The above code can (and should) be written as (well, it *could* be simplified more, but this question is not about PEP-8):

```
self.feed('conv5_3').conv(3, 3, 512, 1, 1,name='rpn_conv/3x3')
self.feed('rpn_conv/3x3').lstm(512 ,128, name='lstm_o')
self.feed('lstm_o').lstm_bbox(128, len(anchor_scales) * 10 * 4, name='rpn_bbox_pred')
self.feed('lstm_o').lstm_bbox(128, len(anchor_scales) * 10 * 2, name='rpn_cls_score')
```